# Авторизация Googel API

Tags: c#, аутентификация

Сейчас моё приложение использует для регистрации .json файл. А как сделать так, что бы пользователь должен был вводить почту и пароль? C#

Comment: _приложение использует для регистрации .json файл_ - код в студию! Интересно, как это...

Comment: Можно бить ссаными тряпками. Понял. Раскаялся.

Comment: @SamJust вопрос уже не актуален?